# Text blur effect via jQuery

Tags: jquery, drupal, blur

I have a text list with the following structure:

```
<div class="text">
<a href="/node/30">Site Text</a>
</div>
```

I want to get a blur effect for the other list items, when the mouse hovers over one list item.

I would like to get the same effect shown on http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/.

[image: before]

[image: after]

How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey check these examples:

yes but you can only blur text here not other things.(In css 2)

but can blur other things too in css 3.

[Example 1](http://motyar.blogspot.in/2010/04/blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery.html)

[Example 2](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/blurry-text/)

**Edit:**

Check this out:

```
<style>
 .hello{color:transparent; text-shadow:0 0 0 #000; font-size:20px;}
 .hello div{float:left; margin:10px;}
 .hello:hover div{text-shadow:0 0 10px #000;}
 .hello:hover div:hover{text-shadow:0 0 0 #000;}
 </style>
  <div class="hello">
    <div>
        new1
    </div>
    <div>
        new2
    </div>
    <div>
        new3
    </div>
    <div>
        new4
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is a simple css based effect use it and enjoy ;)

Comment: thank you but i don't understand. Example 1, making blur effect on all texts.

Comment: ???!!!! 
Actually, the trick is that you have to just remove the color of the text and rely only on text shadow for the effect.

Comment: yes, its working but on all texts. I want, when mouseover an element, get blur effect other elements.

Comment: okh use javascript event `onmousehover` and `onmouseout` then change every other element's class according to your needs....


And beware:  [http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html)

Before using.

Comment: But i don't change other element class. Can i seperate myclass:hover and myclass? When active myclass:hover, get blur effect myclass?

Comment: @user1213807: Check the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.text a').blur(function() {
    //Add your styles
}
```

Comment: jQuery's `blur()` has nothing to do with the effect the OP wants; it's an event binder... http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

```
$("#ElementID").hover(function(){
  $("#OtherElementId").blur();
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `blur()` has nothing to do with the effect the OP wants; it's an event binder... http://api.jquery.com/blur/